# How do I generate random dates in excel via a certain distribution?

Tags: vba, excel, date

I need to generate X(take 1000 for ease of use) random dates between certain years for example between 1/1/1950 and 1/1/2000 where the mean is around 1/1/1980(1957-1985)

Now I know that Excel date calculation is based on the amount of days.
So:

```
01/01/1950  = 18264
01/01/2000  = 36526
01/01/1980  = 29221
```

So the min is 18264 and the max is 36526. where the mean is 29221 where most is generated between 27395 and 31048.

With what method could I achieve this, that is either possible via excel formula's or either VBA.

Right now I am generating the dates with this: `=RANDBETWEEN(DATE(1950,1,1),DATE(2000,1,1))`

but this does, of course, does not give me the wanted data. As I am not looking for an uniform distribution.

Can someone steer me in the right direction, I have not been able to find or achieve this.

**update** 
The distribution I am looking for would look something like this:
[image]

where -5 is 1950 and 5 is 2000. I would either get the purple graph, or red, or green or blue. Not all at once. F*or the sake of the question lets go with purple graph*

**Update2**
The eventual graph that I would like to be able to produce with the randomized data would look something like this. By changing the parameters the entire graph could shift a different way. 
[image]

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What *distribution* do you want?

Comment: I don't know if a normal distribution is possible where the mean would be close to the maximum value. I have been looking at the poisson distribution but when I read in to it, I don't think this is the right distribution.

Comment: Or, why  doesn't `=RANDBETWEEN(DATE(1950,1,1),DATE(2000,1,1))` give you the wanted data? It gives me a nice random date with uniform distribution between your dates.

Comment: There are infinitely many distributions which have a range [1950,1999) and a mean of  1980. Your problem description is radically under-determined.

Comment: @PA His requirements rule out a uniform distribution

Comment: I know, I just wanted to get OP better describe the requirements.

Comment: which one of the 4 depicted?

Comment: I updated the question with how I would so the distribution. The =RANDBETWEEN(DATE(1950,1,1),DATE(2000,1,1)) gives me random data, but as John indeed pointed out I dont want a uniform distribution. I would for example only want the purple.

Comment: Your requirements describe an asymmetric distribution but the pictures that you show are all symmetric hence shed little light on what you are trying to acheive

Comment: Looks like you want a normal distribution. But I'd need the variance as well as the mean.

Comment: @Bathsheba the variance could change on the specification of the data that I want to generate. Same goes with the mean.

John Coleman I added another picture and explanation.

Comment: @Bathsheba lets say 1980 with a variance of 20

Comment: Just removed my previous comment since it looks like you *don't* want a normal distribution.

Comment: @Bathsheba a normal distribution would suffice, it would give me a distribution I do not have at this moment. The added picture would be an ideal situation. I just don't have a clue how I would make a distribution in the data at all. Normal distribution would definitely count as an answer

Comment: @JBom But a normal distribution *can't* satisfy your requirements since it is 1) symmetric but you want a skewed distribution, 2) has infinite range but you want a finite range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you need a beta distribution with a ratio of 2/3. The problem with a normal distribution is its symmetry and moreover, it does not have a Max and Min. The beta distribution provides these.

Try this:

```
=BETA.INV(RAND(), 3, 2, 18264, 36526)
```

Comment: that.. seems to be the correct solution. I can change the distribution as well as the min and max. This seems to be the closest and simplest solution!

Answer (score 2):

The formula `=NORM.INV(RAND(), 29221, SQRT(20))` would create normally distributed random drawings with a variance of 20 and a mean 29221 (which corresponds to 1-Jan-1980). You'll probably want the *parameters* to refer to other cells rather than being hardcoded in the formula. Note that SQRT(20) corresponds to *days*.

Older versions of Excel have the equivalent `NORMINV` function.

These are the *quantile* functions of your distribution.

If you want another shape (such as the skewed distribution in your question), then you'll need to build the quantile function yourself. You can do this by converting your PDF into a CDF (by an integration), and exchanging the axes. Probably a job for VBA.

Comment: With your given formula I am able to generate some random data for 1000 records which give me a normal distribution. The 20 that I referred to in the previous comment would be 20 years, this would be 7300 if I am correct? 

By changing the 20 to 7300, the distribution still ranges around 1979 and 1980. I will look in the skewness, this is something that came up as well when John came with asymetric distribution. You helped me further!

Comment: No, the variance is in days squared.